# Is there a way to reread tutorial prompts?

Tags: elden-ring

I accidentally dismissed a tutorial prompt in Elden Ring before I finished reading it. Is there a way to reread past tutorial prompts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**. Open your inventory > Switch tabs to the right (pressing <kbd>R1</kbd> on PlayStation or <kbd>RB</kbd> on Xbox) > Until the last tab on the right. And there you have your tutorial prompts.